# C# 6 auto-properties - read once or every time?

Tags: c#, automatic-properties, c#-6.0

I follow a pattern when setting certain properties whereby I check to see if the corresponding field is empty, returning the field if not and setting it if so.  I frequently use this for reading configuration settings, for example, so that the setting is read lazily and so that it is only read once.  Here is an example:

```
private string DatabaseId
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseId))
        {
            databaseId = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
        }

        return databaseId;
    }
}
```

I have started to use C# 6 autoproperty initialization as it really cleans up and makes my code more concise.  I would like to do something like this:

```
private string DatabaseId { get; } = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
```

But I'm not sure how the compiler interprets it in this case.  Will this have the same effect as my first block of code, setting the (automatically implemented) field once, and thereafter reading from the field?  Or will this call the `CloudConfigurationManager` every time I get `DatabaseId`?

Comment: Yes it is an initializer, to avoid all that code

Comment: @Ivan Try wrapping the call to `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database")` in another function, putting a breakpoint on it, and seeing if it gets called multiple times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you show:

```
private string DatabaseId { get; } = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
```

Is an "Auto-Property Initializer", keyword being "initializer", from [MSDN Blogs: C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

> The auto-property initializer allows assignment of properties directly within their declaration. For read-only properties, it takes care of all the ceremony required to ensure the property is immutable.

Initializers run once per instance (or once per type for static members). See [C# Language Specification, 10.4.5 Variable initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645757(v=vs.71).aspx):

> For instance fields, variable initializers correspond to assignment statements that are executed when an instance of the class is created.

So that code compiles to something like this:

```
public class ContainingClass
{
    private readonly string _databaseId;
    public string DatabaseId { get { return _databaseId; } }

    public ContainingClass()
    {
        _databaseId = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
    }       
}
```

For static variables, this kind of looks the same:

```
private static string DatabaseId { get; } = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
```

Compiles to, more or less:

```
public class ContainingClass
{
    private static readonly string _databaseId;
    public static string DatabaseId { get { return _databaseId; } }

    static ContainingClass()
    {
        _databaseId = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
    }       
}
```

Though not entirely, as when the type doesn't have a static constructor, "static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class".

Answer (score 10):

C# 6.0 readonly auto property will create a field and invoke the initializer only once.

However, that is not equal to what you have there. In your code, `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` will be called only when someone reads the `DatabaseId` property but with "readonly auto property" `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` will be called at the time of class initialization itself.

This difference may/mayn't matter. It depends. If the call is expensive then you can use `Lazy<T>` which is roughly equal to what you have.

Answer (score 2):

It will set the value only once and after that just read it.

However there's a slight difference in the sense that you now no longer have a `databaseId` field. In your first example you basically check for `id == null || id == ""` to set the database string. That means that if you create a new instance with `databaseId` set to an empty string, the first example will still get the ID from the settings.

The second example however will see that empty string as a valid value and remain with it.

First code:

```
if(id == null || id == "") // Get ID from settings
```

Second code:

```
if(id == null) // Get ID from settings
```

Answer (score 1):

An auto-property has automatically a backing field. In this case, this field will only be assignable from the constructor or from the auto-property initializer. Your new code is better than the first one. It will only make one call to `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");`. In the first example, you have to make a check every time your property `get` is called.

Comment: "Better" is relative. How long does it take to call CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting?  if (and I'm being excessive intentionally here) took say 1 minute to make the call, and your class might not need to make it at all unless it was USING the property, you could save a minute with his implementation at the cost of a microsecond to check vs null /empty)

Comment: 8 years later I find my answer very lacking... you're right, it's basically lazy initialization and probably better practice in general. If there's any kind of IO (network, disk, deserialization), I'd recommend not using a property but an async method with caching (if it applies). this way, you let the consumer worry about the time it might take.

Answer (score 0):

you could change your code to:  (Fixing a few things along the way)
(btw, my preference is to use _DatabaseId for the name)

```
private string databaseId;
public string DatabaseId
{
    get
    {
       return databaseId ??= CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");
    }
}
```

Which will call the method to GetSetting If and only If, the property is read.

This approach can be useful in situations where you might have a lot of List's and they take a lot of work go off and generate the list, so you don't want to do that unless someone actually uses it, in fact, you don't even want to create the List object.

One nice side effect of this would be that it will not require a constructor to be added, with a bunch of foo= new's in it.  It is isolated to the property being defined, and if one list accesses another list it will cascade and create only what is actually needed to return the data that you are requesting.

PS: You could even do it in 2 lines:

```
private string databaseId;
public string DatabaseId { get {return databaseId ??= CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("database");}  }
```

If you want to keep it compact...